# Utilizando sticky, cuando hago scroll el contexto del main se va por encima de la barra de navegación

Tags: html, css, sticky

Siento que el problema no solo radica en el bloque de la función y sea en la estructura antes del mismo.

> Por eso como un buen principiante he publicado todo el código para mí no siendo innecesario.

Quería que vieran la estructura padre.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "CuerpoFont";
    src: url(./Fuentes/Montserrat-VariableFont_wght.woff), url("https://github.com/likemetamorfosys/PrimeraWebSportsCourts/raw/db16c1f6294ccc37bd76fdef8e81ba0a300c660d/SportCourts/Fuentes/Montserrat-VariableFont_wght.woff");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "TituloFont";
    src: url(./Fuentes/VictorMono-Italic-.woff), url("https://github.com/likemetamorfosys/PrimeraWebSportsCourts/raw/main/SportCourts/Fuentes/VictorMono-Italic-.woff");
}
html{
    background-color: rgb(64, 52, 52),;
    font-family: "CuerpoFont";
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.201),rgba(38, 255, 0, 0.646)),url(./Imagenes/24824.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    padding-bottom:90vh;
}
#tITULAR{
    backdrop-filter: blur(6px);
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
h1{
    width: 570px;
    height: 170px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 
    margin: 1PX 50%;
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    font-family: "TituloFont";
    font-size: 80px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.247);
    border: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom: 0;
}
body{
    margin-top: 250px;
    max-width: 700px;   
}
#lemaDelTitulo{
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    font-weight: 1000;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 75px 29.2%;
    width: 970px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.329);
    backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
    font-size: 14.5px;
    color: rgb(255, 254, 254);
    border: 7px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style:dotted;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    border-style: solid;
}
.seccionItem{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    align-items: center;
}
#scrollNav{
    text-decoration: none;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -50%;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding: 0 35px;
}
li{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 26.2px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 100px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translate(50%);
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: rgb(34, 20, 20);
    border-style:ridge;
    border-color: rgb(241, 98, 98);
}
li:hover{
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
main{
    height: 150vh;
    padding-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translate(50%,50%);
    color: aliceblue;
    margin-block: 124.4px;
}
article h2{
    background-color: gold;
    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.titularesSticky{
    text-overflow: ;
    position: sticky;
    top: -410.4px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
    backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
    border-style:dotted;
}
p{
    MARGIN:0 45px -40px;
}
.parra{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.748);
    font-style:italic;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-weight:lighter;
    transform: traslate(-50%);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.386);
    border-color: gold;
}
.contenedor1{
    top: -px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, init ial-scale=1.0">
  <title>SportsCourts</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./Imagenes/sports.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CssMod.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 id="tITULAR">SportsCourts</h1>
    <p id="lemaDelTitulo">Now you can explore where and how players play.</p>
  </header>
  <nav id="scrollNav">
    <li>
      <a href="#homeLink" class="seccionItem">Home</a>

      <a href="" class="seccionItem">Login</a>

      <a href="" class="seccionItem">Courts Locations</a>

      <a href="#aboutLink" class="seccionItem">About Us</a>

      <a href="#securityLink" class="seccionItem">About Security</a>
    </li>
  </nav>

  <main>

    <div class="contenedor1">

      <article class="section1" id="homeLink">

        <h2 class="titularesSticky">Home</h2>
        <p class="parra">blablabla</p>

      </article>

      <article class="section1" id="aboutLink">

        <h2 class="titularesSticky">About us</h2>
        <p class="parra">blablbabla</p>

      </article>

      <article class="section1" id="securityLink">

        <h2 class="titularesSticky">About Security</h2>
        <p class="parra">blablabla </p>

      </article>

    </div>

  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Buen día, para poder ayudarte y reproducir tu problema, tendrías que adjuntar el código como texto con su respectivo formato y no en imágenes.

Comment: Hola, haz el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Comment: De repente es porque no sabes como formatear el codigo que no te lo permite. ` 3 de este simbolo para um bloque de codigo o cuatro espacio o mas por linea para poner una linea o mas de codigo. ``` o espacio;espacio;espacio;espacio;codes

Comment: Muchas gracias por atenderme y no demosatrar apatia en mi ignorancia. No se como lo logre publicar en esta ocasion de hecho, se me hizo mas dificil entender y publicar aqui que crear una web con html. y css lol

Comment: Según entiendo el título que te recomendé es tu problema ¿Verdad??.

Comment: Ninguna de sus sugerencias por el momento señor, mi problema resumido es que el comportamiento sticky lo considero anormal ya que se adhiere al tope del navegador pero por la parte de abajo del contenido cuando mi intencion es que valla por encima del contenido mientras se desplaza. Si no entiendes mis especificaciones creo que no eres el indicado para ayudar

Comment: o no explicas bien o tienes razon y no soy.

Answer (score 1):

La solución que creo que buscas lo resuelves con `z-index`, este indica el orden de un elemento posicionado y sus descendientes. Cuando varios elementos se superponen, los elementos con mayor valor `z-index` cubren aquellos con menor valor.

Quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
#scrollNav{
    text-decoration: none;
    position: sticky;
  /*Aqui asignas la medida de superposicion*/
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -50%;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding: 0 35px;
}
```

Dime si te funciono.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "CuerpoFont";
  src: url(./Fuentes/Montserrat-VariableFont_wght.woff), url("https://github.com/likemetamorfosys/PrimeraWebSportsCourts/raw/db16c1f6294ccc37bd76fdef8e81ba0a300c660d/SportCourts/Fuentes/Montserrat-VariableFont_wght.woff");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "TituloFont";
  src: url(./Fuentes/VictorMono-Italic-.woff), url("https://github.com/likemetamorfosys/PrimeraWebSportsCourts/raw/main/SportCourts/Fuentes/VictorMono-Italic-.woff");
}

html {
  background-color: rgb(64, 52, 52), ;
  font-family: "CuerpoFont";
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.201), rgba(38, 255, 0, 0.646)), url(./Imagenes/24824.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  padding-bottom: 90vh;
}

#tITULAR {
  backdrop-filter: blur(6px);
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

h1 {
  width: 570px;
  height: 170px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1PX 50%;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  font-family: "TituloFont";
  font-size: 80px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.247);
  border: 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

body {
  margin-top: 250px;
  max-width: 700px;
}

#lemaDelTitulo {
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  font-weight: 1000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 75px 29.2%;
  width: 970px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.329);
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  font-size: 14.5px;
  color: rgb(255, 254, 254);
  border: 7px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.seccionItem {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  align-items: center;
}

#scrollNav {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: sticky;
  /*Aqui asignas la medida de superposicion*/
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -50%;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding: 0 35px;
}

li {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 26.2px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 100px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(50%);
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: rgb(34, 20, 20);
  border-style: ridge;
  border-color: rgb(241, 98, 98);
}

li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

main {
  height: 150vh;
  padding-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  color: aliceblue;
  margin-block: 124.4px;
}

article h2 {
  background-color: gold;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.titularesSticky {
  text-overflow: ;
  position: sticky;
  top: -410.4px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  border-style: dotted;
}

p {
  MARGIN: 0 45px -40px;
}

.parra {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.748);
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  transform: traslate(-50%);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.386);
  border-color: gold;
}

.contenedor1 {
  top: -px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, init ial-scale=1.0">
  <title>SportsCourts</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./Imagenes/sports.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CssMod.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 id="tITULAR">SportsCourts</h1>
    <p id="lemaDelTitulo">Now you can explore where and how players play.</p>
  </header>
  <nav id="scrollNav">
    <li>
      <a href="#homeLink" class="seccionItem">Home</a>

      <a href="" class="seccionItem">Login</a>

      <a href="" class="seccionItem">Courts Locations</a>

      <a href="#aboutLink" class="seccionItem">About Us</a>

      <a href="#securityLink" class="seccionItem">About Security</a>
    </li>
  </nav>

  <main>

    <div class="contenedor1">

      <article class="section1" id="homeLink">

        <h2 class="titularesSticky">Home</h2>
        <p class="parra">blablabla</p>

      </article>

      <article class="section1" id="aboutLink">

        <h2 class="titularesSticky">About us</h2>
        <p class="parra">blablbabla</p>

      </article>

      <article class="section1" id="securityLink">

        <h2 class="titularesSticky">About Security</h2>
        <p class="parra">blablabla </p>

      </article>

    </div>

  </main>

</body>

</html>
```